# How to redirect to home page(in jsx) after logout in react

Tags: html, redirect, reactjs, jsx

```
<li>
    <a href="homepage.jsx">
      <i className="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> 
      Log Out
    </a>
</li>
```

I am having homepage component in `homepage.jsx`, after clicking on `logout` i need to go to homepage component.

Help me in this.

Comment: are you using react-router?

Comment: yes I am using React-router
<IndexRoute component={HomePage} />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `react-router`, so instead of using `a` and `href` use `Link`, write it like this:

```
<li>
    <Link to="/">
        <i className="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> 
        Log Out
    </Link>
</li>
```

Since Homepage component is your `indexroute`, so navigation to `/` will `render` it.

If you want to navigate dynamically means inside any function, then check this answer:

[Programmatically navigating in React-Router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137774/programmatically-navigating-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: <div className="fields clearfix">
                    <div className="six_group">
                      <div className="nombs"> <span>1</span> </div>
                      <div className="nombs"> <span>5</span> </div>
                      <div className="nombs"> <span>6</span> </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    </div>


I am having the number i need to press value and make validation that first 2 numbers should only start with either 11 or 12

Comment: didn't get you, in this no input field is present where you are pressing the value ? can you post the complete code ?

Comment: <input id="id" className="nombs" type="number" pattern="^\d{6}\d{6}\d{4}$" required />

Comment: i need the number to be printed in - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - -  like this
But i am able to print 1234567891234567 in this format and I need to do validation that the starting 2 numbers are 11, 12,13,14

Comment: ^\d{0,1}([1][1-9]+)|^\d{0,1}([2][1]+)|^\d{0,1}([3][1-6]+)|^\d{0,1}([5][1-3]+)|^\d{0,1}([6][1-4]+)|^\d{0,1}([7][1-6]+)|^\d{0,1}([8][1-2]+)|^\d{0,1}(([9][1]+)|([9][4]+))
For value validation i am having this how to implement in jsx in react

Comment: can you show your code in `jsfiddle` or on `pastebin`? need to see your code. atleast paste some part.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using react-router v 2.x.x.
You can create a component like below for this.

Your route should also contain the route to which you want to redirect.

```
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
       <Route path="/homepage" component={Homepage}/>
   </Route>
```

```js
class Logout extends React.Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            error:null
        };
    }

    logOut() {
        Api.logOut().then(
            () => {
                this.context.router.replace('/homepage');
            },
            () => {
                this.setState({
                    error:'Error occured while logging out. Please try again.'
                });
            }
        );
    }

    render(){

        return (
       <li>
          <a onClick={this.logOut} >
             <i className="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> 
             Log Out
          </a>
       </li>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Logout/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling function to redirection on Logout button clicked on jsx component header.jsx
below code redirect to login page

```
logoutCall = () => {
    window.localStorage.clear();
};  
goLogin = () => {
   window.localStorage.clear();
   <Link to="/login"></Link>
  };    


<Link className="linkLogoutClass" to="/login" onClick={this.logoutCall}><img style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} className="logoutImageStyle " src={logout} onClick={this.goLogin}   ></img> Logout</Link>
```