# Programmatically navigating in React-Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

How can I move to a new page after some validation is done with `React Router V4`? I have something like this:

```
export class WelcomeForm extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if(this.validateForm())
            // send to '/life'

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="WelcomeForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input className="minutes" type="number" value={this.state.minutes} onChange={ (e) => this.handleChanges(e, "minutes")}/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to send the user to another route. I had a look at Redirect but it seems like it would delete the current page from the history which I don't want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using [react-router v4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start), so you need to use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) with your component to access the history object’s properties, then use `history.push` to change the route dynamically.

**[withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter):**

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest
>   's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter
>   will re-render its component every time the route changes with the
>   same props as  render props: { match, location, history }.

Like this:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class WelcomeForm extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(this.validateForm())
            this.props.history.push("/life");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="WelcomeForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input className="minutes" type="number" value={this.state.minutes} onChange={ (e) => this.handleChanges(e, "minutes")}/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(WelcomeForm);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it gives me this error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'. Any simpler ways?

Comment: use this: `this.props.history.push("/life");` check the updated answer.

Comment: yes it seems to work. I would like to understand why redirect explained in other answers does not seem to work and which of the two is the better practice

Comment: both the ways are correct, but redirect will work when you render it, means it is a ui component so inside render method use some condition and return Redirect from there it will work, but in that answer he was simply putting that inside a method it that case it will not work i think.

Comment: Hi, I tried your approach, however `this.props` does not contain history for me :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199064/how-to-programmatically-navigate-to-new-path-using-hashrouter?noredirect=1#comment77365323_45199064

Comment: @LeonGaban are you rendering the component in `withRouter` HOC like this:  `export default withRouter(WelcomeForm);` check the full code as i suggested.

Comment: Ah thanks! Yes I was missing `export default withRouter(LoginContainer)` in the export statement

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher-order component which will inject [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object as property. Then you can use `history.push` to make redirection:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...

class WelcomeForm extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(this.validateForm())
            this.props.history.push('/life');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="WelcomeForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input className="minutes" type="number" value={this.state.minutes} onChange={ (e) => this.handleChanges(e, "minutes")}/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(WelcomeForm);
```

To make redirection you can also use `<Redirect to="/someURL" />` in some cases but this component have to be **rendered** so you have to use it somewhere in JSX.

Comment: Dear downvoter please explain why did you downvote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Depending on how you want your redirect to behave there are several options: [React router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)**

**Redirect component**

> Rendering a  will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

`to: string` - The URL to redirect to.
`to: object` - A location to redirect to.
`push: bool` - When true, redirecting will push a new entry onto the history instead of replacing the current one.

Example: `<Redirect push to="/somewhere"/>`

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'


export class WelcomeForm extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if(this.validateForm())
            <Redirect push to="/life"/>

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="WelcomeForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input className="minutes" type="number" value={this.state.minutes} onChange={ (e) => this.handleChanges(e, "minutes")}/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

**Using `withRouter` HoC**

> This higher order component will inject the same props as Route. However, it carries along the limitation that you can have only 1 HoC per file.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export class WelcomeForm extends Component {

        handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(this.validateForm())
            this.props.history.push("/life");

        }
        render() {
            return (
                <form className="WelcomeForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input className="minutes" type="number" value={this.state.minutes} onChange={ (e) => this.handleChanges(e, "minutes")}/>
                </form>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks. As I wrote in my question, I fear Redirect delete the current page from the browser history

Comment: Are you sure it will work? According to docs only rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. and  you don't render it.

Comment: if you add `push`it will keep the history.

Comment: add push where?

Comment: i'm afraid it doesnt work: it says: 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions'

Comment: Hi would you mind a look? I tried all the answers in this question, but none worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199064/how-to-programmatically-navigate-to-new-path-using-hashrouter?noredirect=1#comment77365323_45199064

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript extends your component using `React.Component<RouteComponentProps>` to get `this.props.history.push` properly

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
    constructor(props: Readonly<RouteComponentProps>) {
        super(props)
    }

    public render(){
        // you can access history programmatically anywhere on this class
        // this.props.history.push("/")
        return (<div/>)
    }
}
return default withRouter(YourComponent)
```