# Programmatically navigating using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to redirect to new page via `onclick` function of a button, 
but its not redirecting.

Here is my code-

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 

class Pricing extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        document.title = "Pricing";
        this.setPlanId = this.setPlanId.bind(this);
    }

    setPlanId(p_id){
       localStorage.setItem('plan_id', p_id);
       //BrowserRouter.push('/do-payment');     
       this.props.history.push("/do-payment");
   }

    render(){                   
            return(
                <div>
                    <div className="pricing bottommargin clearfix">
                        <Link to="#" className="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg bgcolor border-color" onClick={this.setPlanId(somevalue)}>Contunue</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );  
    }
}

export default Pricing;
```

Please let me know, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: First of all it should be `onClick={this.setPlanId}`. Then are you sure you can use `BrowserRouter` this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-navigate-dynamically-using-react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137774/how-to-navigate-dynamically-using-react-router-dom)

Comment: @MayankShukla , yes its duplicate and I applied same `import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'; `   and  `this.props.history.push("/do-payment");`  in respective function. .............but its redirecting automatically without on click event...

Comment: actually I am passing value to function to set in localStorage. Please check updated code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question was duplicate of: [How to navigate dynamically using react router dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137774/how-to-navigate-dynamically-using-react-router-dom)

Answer of updated Ques.

Write it like this:

```
render(){                   
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="pricing bottommargin clearfix">
                <Link 
                      to="#" 
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg bgcolor border-color" 
                      onClick={() => this.setPlanId(somevalue)}
                >
                      Contunue
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );  
}
```

**Reason:** `onClick` expect a `function` but you are assigning a value by calling that function, you don't need to call that method it will get called whenever user click on that.

Use `arrow function` like this:

```
onClick={() => this.setPlanId(somevalue)}
```

or

```
onClick={this.setPlanId.bind(this, somevalue)}
```

And remove the method binding from `constructor` that will not be required after this.

**Full Code:**

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 

class Pricing extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        document.title = "Pricing";
    }

    setPlanId(p_id){
       localStorage.setItem('plan_id', p_id);    
       this.props.history.push("/do-payment");
   }

    render(){                   
            return(
                <div>
                    <div className="pricing bottommargin clearfix">
                        <Link to="#" className="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg bgcolor border-color" onClick={() => this.setPlanId(somevalue)}>Contunue</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );  
    }
}

export default Pricing;
```