# How routing to home can be done in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am new to React.I am trying to change the route inside a function.I am used react-router-dom for routing.I used `"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1".`The function is,

```
 LogIn(email, password){

            this.props.LogInAction(email, password);
            if(this.props.loginstatus == true){

                    /* Here I need to go to '/home' */

            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate dynamically using react router dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137774/how-to-navigate-dynamically-using-react-router-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `withRouter` on page like this:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And then use this to make redirection as:

```
if(this.props.loginstatus == true){
    this.props.history.push('/home');
}
```

And don't forget to declare `withRouter` while exporting class as:

```
export default withRouter(className);
```

Comment: It leads to an error for me. `./src/component/login.js
51:4-18 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'`

Comment: @sojan Do you have react-router installed?

Comment: @sojan `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani yes , I installed. And version is `"react-router": "^4.1.1`

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I imported `import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`. and I used `BrowserRouter.push('/home');` for route.
A new error `Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_react_router_dom__.a.push is not a function`

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani  `import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';  ' browserHistory.push('/home');`  results an error `./src/component/login.js
  Line 28:  'browserHistory' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.`

Answer (score 1):

If you use react-router, inside you class

```
pushHistory() {
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }

LogIn(email, password){

            this.props.LogInAction(email, password);
            if(this.props.loginstatus == true){

                   this.props.history.push("/");

            }
```

and your routes wrapped like this:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

    <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={ App }/>
                    <Route exact path="/users" component={ UserList }/>
                    <Route exact path="/user/new" component={ UserCreate }/>
                    <Route path="/users/:id" component={ UserDetail }/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: If you have `exact={true}` you can just write it as `exact`.

Comment: yeah, i know) but tnk u.

Comment: @Evgeniy Volk . In the above code in route  there is no common layout.How can I done routing if there is a common layout