# react router link is not working reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use react-router navigation in a button.

**dashboard.js**

```
handleClick() {
   <Link to="/deneme">Deneme</Link>;
   console.log('clicked!');
}

<Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Hesapla</Button>
```

And i configured my route like:

**index.js**

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Full}/>
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

**Full.js**

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/deneme" name="Deneme" component={Deneme} />
</Switch>
```

`handleClick` working but link doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Link` is a ui element, you have to render it inside render method and onClick of that link will take you to that page, putting  Link inside a method will not redirect you to that page.

You have two options:

**1-** Put that Link inside render method where you define the handle click, means like this:

```
<Button color="primary">
    <Link to='/deneme'>Hesapla</Link>
</Button>
```

And remove `handleClick` method.

**2-** Another way is, navigate dynamically by pushing the route into history, like this:

```
handleClick() {
   this.props.history.push('/deneme');
}
```

For more details check this answer: [How to navigate dynamically using react router dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137774/how-to-navigate-dynamically-using-react-router-dom)

Assuming you are using `React-Router V4.`

Comment: i tried your first solution and nothing happen but second, im getting 'this.props is undefined'

Comment: i solved finally. i put link outside of button and worked .

Comment: great, you got the solution, i think reason for `this.props` is undefined, is you forgot to bind the `handleClick` method, put this line in the constructor: `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`.

Comment: I still dont understand bind logic but thank you again

Comment: is it working after binding? check this answer you will get a better idea why and when binding is required: [Why is JavaScript bind() necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391288/why-is-javascript-bind-necessary)

Comment: Yeap it worked too.Now im looking your link thank you so much.