# Programmatically redirecting inside child component in React JS is not working

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I am developing a web application using React JS. Now, I am trying to programmatically redirect to another route. I can redirect like this.

```
this.props.history.push('/event/${this.props.id}/edit');
```

But when I use that in the child component it is not working. This is my scenario. I have a parent component called, EventListComponent. Inside that component, I render another child component called EventWidgetComponent. I am redirecting in the child component. But this.props.history is always undefined when I use it in the child component. How can I fix it?

Comment: are you passing `history` through props?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because your child component doesn't have the access to history. Child component is receiving the props from parent component not from `Router`, that's why.

These are the possible ways to solve the issue:

**1-** Either pass a method from parent to child and do the redirecting part inside parent component. Call that method from child component for redirecting.

**2-** Use [**withRouter**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) hoc and render the child component inside that, it will provide access of history to child component.

Like this:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

// Child component here

class Child extends React.Component {
   // code
}

export default withRouter(Child)
```

Check this answer: [Programmatically navigating in React-Router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137774/programmatically-navigating-in-react-router-v4)

**3-** Pass the reference of history to child in props:

```
<Child history={this.props.history} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Adequate answer. Cheers. BTW. It is not coming home.

Comment: But second option throw this error. Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {pathname, search, hash, state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: that error means somewhere in the code you are rendering the `history object`, that contains `pathname, search, state etc`, something like this: `<div>{this.props.history}</div>`. Objects are not a valid element, render the specific value :)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `history` prop down from the component you are giving to a `Route` to the child component if you want to use it there.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* ... */}
        <Route exact path="/" component={Parent} />
        {/* ... */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child history={this.props.history} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a prop to the EventWidgetComponent passed from the parent EventListComponent like onHistoryPush:

```
<EventWidgetComponent onHistoryPush={() => this.props.history.push('/event/${this.props.id}/edit')}
```