# Redirect in react-router-dom doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
handleLogin() {
  const { username, password } = this.state;
  if (username === 'test' && password === '1234') {
    this.setState({ error: false });
    auth.authenticate();
    alert('done')
    return <Redirect to="/"/>
  } else {
    this.setState({ error: true });
  }
}
```

This function is an onClick handler for my buttong.
Whenever I type in the right id and pw, I intend to redirect the user to the `"/"` route.
The alert gets called but it doesn't get redirected to the path.
Is this the right usage?

Comment: `<Redirect />` is a component you need to render in a component's `render` method for it to redirect. You can use `this.props.history.push` or `this.props.history.replace` instead if your want to redirect programmatically.

Comment: @Tholle That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Redirect />` is a component you need to render in a component's render method for it to redirect. You can use [`history.push` or `history.replace`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation) instead if your want to redirect programmatically.

If the component is not used directly in a `Route`, you can use the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC to get access to the `history` object in the `props`.

```
handleLogin() {
  const { username, password } = this.state;
  if (username === 'test' && password === '1234') {
    this.setState({ error: false });
    auth.authenticate();
    alert('done')
    this.props.history.push('/');
  } else {
    this.setState({ error: true });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` is a ui element, and `handleLogin` is a event handler, it will not render the element. To navigate dynamically you need to push a new entry into history.

If you are rendering that component in some route then, use `this.props.history.push`. If the component is child of some other component then use [**withRouter**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) to get the access of history object first then do the `history.push`.

Check this answer: [Programmatically navigating in React-Router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137774/programmatically-navigating-in-react-router-v4)

Like this:

```
handleLogin() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    if (username === 'test' && password === '1234') {
        this.setState({ error: false });
        auth.authenticate();
        alert('done')

        this.props.history.push('/');

    } else {
        this.setState({ error: true });
    }
}
```