# What is the best way to redirect a page using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am new to React Router and learn that there are so many ways to redirect a page:

1. Using `browserHistory.push("/path")`

   ```
   import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
   //do something...
   browserHistory.push("/path");
   ```
2. Using `this.context.router.push("/path")`

   ```
   class Foo extends React.Component {
       constructor(props, context) {
           super(props, context);
           //do something...
       }
       redirect() {
           this.context.router.push("/path")
       }
   }

   Foo.contextTypes = {
       router: React.PropTypes.object
   }
   ```
3. In React Router v4, there's `this.context.history.push("/path")` and `this.props.history.push("/path")`. Details: [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

I'm so confused by all these options, is there a best way to redirect a page?

Comment: you are using v4 yes?

Comment: the link to the other stack you posted is pretty clear, I would recommend using `withRouter`

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Actually it depends on your use case.

**1) You want to protect your route from unauthorized users**

If that is the case you can use the component called `<Redirect />` and can implement the following logic:

```
import React from 'react'
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProtectedComponent = () => {
  if (authFails)
    return <Redirect to='/login'  />
  }
  return <div> My Protected Component </div>
}
```

Keep in mind that if you want `<Redirect />` to work the way you expect, you should place it inside of your component's render method so that it should eventually be considered as a DOM element, otherwise it won't work.

**2) You want to redirect after a certain action (let's say after creating an item)**

In that case you can use history:

```
myFunction() {
  addSomeStuff(data).then(() => {
      this.props.history.push('/path')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

or

```
myFunction() {
  addSomeStuff()
  this.props.history.push('/path')
}
```

In order to have access to history, you can wrap your component with an HOC called `withRouter`. When you wrap your component with it, it passes `match` `location` and `history` props. For more detail please have a look at the official documentation for [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).

If your component is a child of a `<Route />` component, i.e. if it is something like `<Route path='/path' component={myComponent} />`, you don't have to wrap your component with `withRouter`, because `<Route />` passes `match`, `location`, and `history` to its child.

**3) Redirect after clicking some element**

There are two options here. You can use `history.push()` by passing it to an `onClick` event:

```
<div onClick={this.props.history.push('/path')}> some stuff </div>
```

or you can use a `<Link />` component:

```
 <Link to='/path' > some stuff </Link>
```

I think the rule of thumb with this case is to try to use `<Link />` first, I suppose especially because of performance.

Comment: It's working for me ` this.props.history.push("/");` **React-router--v4.2** Thanks @Cagri

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579292/redirection-not-working-because-of-order-of-executions-of-functions/60579404?noredirect=1#comment107174072_60579404 Could you please have a look at this qs?

Comment: In the last option, because the component has `history` in its props to be able to do `this.props.history.push('/path')`, it means that component is a child of `<Route/>` or it has `withRouter` wrapper in export correct?

Comment: So it is possible to route to another component without specifying `<Route path='/path' component={Comp}/>`, I guess just plain `render() { return <Comp/>}` in a condition?

Comment: @Andre yep that's correct for the use of `this.props.history` however I am not sure if I got your second question correct? What do you exactly mean by `route to another component`?

Comment: @CagriYardimci Thanks. Also in that 3rd option, shouldn't the `onClick` have an arrow function with the `history.push` to prevent it from calling prematurely?

Comment: @Andre probably, but the code I provided mostly made up to just provide some alternatives :) So you might need to adjust a bit to make it work

Comment: The method this.props.history.push('/path') almost worked perfectly for me. Problem is that, I suspect that it loads a page from some kind of cache, as I had visited the page, and the query I sent, should make the page look different, but it didn´t. Any additional solution on this?

Comment: Note that in step 1, in the release of React Router v6, the `Redirect` component was removed and replaced with the `Navigate` component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086387/how-to-redirect-to-home-pagein-jsx-after-logout-in-react/77287123#77287123

Answer (score 30):

You can also use react router dom library useHistory;

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Answer (score 16):

Now with react-router `v15.1` and onwards we can `useHistory` hook, This is super simple and clear way. Here is a simple example from the source blog.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function BackButton({ children }) {
  let history = useHistory()
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

You can use this within any functional component and custom hooks. **And yes this will not work with class components same as any other hook.**

Learn more about this here https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#usehistory

Answer (score 2):

You also can `Redirect` within the `Route` as follows. This is for handle invalid routes.

```
<Route path='*' render={() => 
     (
       <Redirect to="/error"/>
     )
}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way: use Link as follows:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to={`your-path`} activeClassName="current">{your-link-name}</Link>
```

If we want to cover the whole div section as link:

```
 <div>
     <Card as={Link} to={'path-name'}>
         .... 
           card content here
         ....
     </Card>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where did you get your `Card` component from? Looks promising but pls show more context for your answer

Comment: `Card` here could be either  react material ui card component or it could be custom UI component created.

eg.
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';