# Redirect in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new in react.js. How to do redirect in react.js after login ? Is it different from Vue.js routing ? I installed [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) package. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router) question. I tried in different ways but no one is working.

Could you please help me with some basic code or any basic tutorial ?

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Auth from '../services/Auth'
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {email: '',password:''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange (event){
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }
    handleClick(){
        var data = {
            client_id: 2,
            client_secret: 'ispGH4SmkEeV4i5Tz9NoI0RSzid5mciG5ecw011f',
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {

            Auth.setToken(responseData.access_token,responseData.expires_in+ Date.now());

            this.props.history.push("/dashboard");  

        })
    }
}

export default Login;
```

I am getting error like below

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code you already tried so we could help you fix it?

Comment: I shared some code @3Dos. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please show the errors?

The component seems incomplete to me.

If you are using `react-router` v4, the component should be wrapped with the [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md). This passes the history prop to the component. Can you please confirm if the `history` prop is not `undefined`?

Apologies if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks @Shishir. I updated the question. That will be helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. Wrapping the component with the withRouter will solve the issue. If It didn't, please let me know, I'll create an example for you to understand the flow.

Comment: Thanks @Shishir. How can I do that ?

Comment: @abuabu I have created an example that shows how the react-router works. https://codesandbox.io/s/qlmrxorl66
Feel free to play around with it. Also, I would recommend going through the [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). And please mark it as the answer if I answered your question correctly. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two way of **redirect** in React.js.

One is using redirect from react-router-dom.

And other is using third-party library i.e. history (this is what you're using)
If you're not getting history in your prop then you need to use withRouter.

example:

```
    import {
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'

    class Login extends React.Component {
      handleSubmit = (user) => {
        saveUser(user).then(() =>
          this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
        ))
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default withRouter(Login)
```

For details, refer:

[How to redirect in react.js with example](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to wrap your app ( basically, app ) with BrowserRouter. Then you need to define Route for your component.

```
<Route to='/dashboard' component={dashboard} {...this.props} />
```

the error you get is because you don't pass the props properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Auth from '../services/Auth'
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class Login extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {email: '',password:''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        //this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange (event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        var data = {
            client_id: 2,
            client_secret: 'ispGH4SmkEeV4i5Tz9NoI0RSzid5mciG5ecw011f',
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {

            Auth.setToken(responseData.access_token,responseData.expires_in+ Date.now());

            this.props.history.push("/dashboard");  

        })
    }
}

export default Login;
```

The difference is an array based function:

```
handleClick = (event) => {}
```

become:

```
handleClick (){}
```