# Redirect to particular page (previous page) after browser is closed using React Router. ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to know, How can I load (redirect) to a particular page(using react-router) after browser session is closed? Suppose, i have logged in and visiting edit-profile page, but i closed the browser, if i open the website again, i could get logged in(as the user details are saved in local storage), but how can i redirect the user to edit-profile page.

I tried the below solution, but i wont have history session once the browser is shut. 
[What is the best way to redirect a page using React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router)

Comment: I would save the current (or previous) page name in the user details in local storage then use the [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to detect whenever the user open a new session.

Comment: @Dyo Can't it be done through **React-router**? The session storage seems like more manual way of doing.

Comment: I don't think React-router has a built-in way to do this, another option is to check if the react router `history.length` equals 1 for a new session but I'm unsure if you can rely on it at 100%.