# ReactJS - Redirect with web browser

Tags: reactjs

Just starting learning ReactJS. I'm trying to redirect using the Redirect component `<Redirect to="/dashboard" />`. However, ReactJS is not familiar with this component by default (getting `Redirect is not defined` on console log).

After some reading, I saw that the Redirect component needs to be imported (`import React from 'react'`). However, since it's a web project, I do not use a webpack but rather import the entire library with:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

So my question(s) is how do I use Redirect for a web project, or rather how to import components for a web project for ReactJS.

Comment: You probably should use Webpack.

Comment: Even after deployment, you won't need so much. Webpack definitely does it for you. Even after these things, you require redirection, use `location.href = 'path/to/redirect';`

Comment: I would say it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router

Answer (score 0):

Redirect component is not part of react. `import React from 'react'` is importing the react object which contains things like `React.Component`.

I'm assuming you mean [Redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/Redirect.js) from `react-router` in which case you should also add a script for [react-router-dom](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/4.3.1/react-router-dom.js) and reference via `ReactRouterDOM.Redirect`.

P.S. If you're creating something you intend to release you're better off generating a project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Nobody uses scripts directly anymore and you are using development versions of babel and react which are slow and large.