# What's the proper way to redirect with React routing when a user is not logged into the application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In a React SPA, I have a collection of "*pages*" under the /src/pages/ folder.

The entry point *page* is an index.js file under the /src/ folder, where I define a router const like this:

```
const routing = (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signIn" component={SignIn} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
        <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
        <Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

It works great and all. All *pages* are navigable like "https://mysuperapp.com/page2" and it will render the Page2 React component.

Concerns arise when I incorporate user session management (log in, log out). If a user is not logged in the app, all *pages* should automatically redirect to the /signIn *page*. And viceversa, if a user is already logged, if the /signIn *page* is accessed, it should automatically redirect to the root homepage.

Right now I have implemented this by adding the following code to **all** the *pages*, right after the render() method is declared in the component, like this:

```
class Page2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (UserProfile.getUserSessionStatus() !== "logged") {
      this.props.history.push("/signIn");
    }
  }

  return (
    JSX code to be rendered here...
    ...
```

This works, but it feels like a cheap workaround used by someone who is just learning React, not by a professional.

For a proof of concept it works, but I would never dare to use such a thing in a production environment.

So, what's the right, best-practices-aligned way to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to redirect a page using React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach is to create a Higher Order component(HOC) and use it for protecting any routes that require login.

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    UserProfile.getUserSessionStatus() === "logged"
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
)
```

And then use like this

```
.....
<PrivateRoute path='/page1' component={Page1} />
.......
```

Hope this helps!