# How can I redirect the user after REST request is resolved

Tags: reactjs, rest, redirect, react-router

I'm trying to redirect the user to the Profile page if the login is successful.

I've tried using the React router redirect as so:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword = (username, password) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_END_DOMAIN + urls.LOGIN, {
      username,
      password,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFTOKEN': Cookies.get("csrftoken"),
      }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.status =='200'){
          return <Redirect to='/profile' />
        }
    });
  });
};
```

But when the login is successful nothing happens.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: what does `console.log` shows ?

Comment: Not important, the status code in the console.log is 200 and the login is successful in the back end.

Comment: Instaed of `Redirect` try `this.props.history.push('/profile')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to redirect a page using React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using React Router 4, then you need to use push method on history object or write  inside render function

```
import history from '../history';

history.push('/profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in following way.

1) take a state value like `this.state = {redirectStatus : false}`

2) as you are checking status code,  set the state  to `true` like so `this.setState({redirectStatus :true})`(if status code is 200)

3) finally you can do some thing like this outside the promise

```
if(redirectStatus ) {
return <Redirect to='/profile' />
}
```

Comment: There is not state in that component, it's purely functional

Comment: @octa Than you can use the hooks to achieve the same, forgot to mention that.