# ReactJs protected route redirect/refresh issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using `react` + `react-router-dom`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And protecting a route by this:

**Router**

```
const Router = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/Panel' component={Panel}></PrivateRoute>
            <Route exact path='/Register' component={Register}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login}></Route>
        </Switch>
    );
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            Auth.getAuth() ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/Login"
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
    />
);
```

**Auth**

```
const Auth = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    authenticate() {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
    },
    signout() {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
    getAuth() {
        return this.isAuthenticated;
    }
};
```

So this working fine and user easily can login, logout, but the problem is when user logged I want to redirect user to `/Panel` route so I tried:

```
window.location.href = "/Panel"
```

OR:

```
this.props.history.push('/Panel')
```

Both redirect to `/Login` again too fast, but If I click on `Panel` link it going to `Panel` route. Second problem is when I refresh page on this address `/Panel` it bring me back to `/Login` again. So what I want to solve are:

1. How to redirect to protected route?
2. How to avoid redirect when refresh page on protected route? *If I type this address and enter it not working too.*

Already seen this topic and tried but no success:

[What is the best way to redirect a page using React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router)

Comment: The value of `isAuthenticated` is store between refreshes. You must save this value in the `LocalStorage`

Comment: Hi tour travel, did you check my answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Yes, but it not solved my issue, I solved with my own solution. But your logic is right and I gave +1 rep. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question:

You can keep the url in the state like this so that after login you can redirect to.

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login",
    state: { from: props.location }
  }}
/>
```

And in Login component, after successfull login you can redirect to:

```
const { state } = this.props.location;
window.location = state ? state.from.pathname : "/";
```

For the second question:

one alternative solution would be keeping the login state in localStorage so that after refreshes the app can read from there. This is generally done sending a jsonwebtoken from login api to the client, and saving the token to the localStorage.