# history.push() not working while sending the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have defined a route in Main component as:

```
<Route path="/user/:action?/:name?" component={DataForm} />
```

MainDataCard component:

```
var data = [ {name: 'abc", label: "ABC", path:"/assets/data/source1.jpg" }, 
             {name: 'pqr", label: "PQR", path:"/assets/data/source2.jpg" },
             {name: 'xyz", label: "XYZ", path:"/assets/data/source3.jpg" },
]
```

I am iterating over a data array and onClick of each card, I ll be navigating to another component which is DataForm. While pushing, I need to send the selected card object.

```
{data.map((card, index) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={index}
            className="cardStyle"
            onClick={() => {
              this.onClickForm(card);
            }}
          >
            <CardContent className="cardContent">
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item md={12}>
                  <img src={card.path} alt="card" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={12}>
                  <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                    {card.name}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>


       onClickForm = card => {
          const {action} = this.props;  // action value can be add/update. Currently action = "add"
          this.props.history.push({
          pathname: `/user/${action}/${card.label}`,
         state: { card: card }
          });
        };
```

In DataForm component, its showing that card is undefined. It means the data is not being sent to DataForm component. Why is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter`? If  the answer is `HashRouter` then that's why. Please clarify so I can give you further explanation, thanks!

Comment: I have found my old answer for further explanation why in `<HashRouter>` case it does not work to pass state, please read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331269/redirecting-to-other-page-using-react-functional-component/59331855#59331855 I hope that helps!

Comment: @norbitrial  I am using HashRouter

Comment: Could you please check the mentioned answer, if that helps you to understand why it was failing? I have explained there the reason for a similar scenario. Thanks!

Comment: I have checked the answer. I cannot use BrowserRouter and in my case, I need to send whole object while pushing to another component. How can I pass whole object in query string?