# Redirection Not Working Because of Order of Executions of Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a login page. If login is successful and token is present in local storage, I want to redirect to a private page /panel. I am calling all functions on the onSubmit() of my form.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
function LoginPage (){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }); 

 const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

function ShowError(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    console.log('Login Not Successful');
  }
}

function FormSubmitted(){
  setSubmitted(true);
  console.log('Form submitted');
}

function RedirectionToPanel(){
  console.log('ha');
  if(submitted && localStorage.getItem('token')){
    console.log('FInall');
    return <Redirect to='/panel'/>
  }
}

  function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    const { email, password } = state;
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    }
  }

    return (
      <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div style={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
              <Avatar>
                <LockOutlinedIcon />
              </Avatar>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                Sign in
              </Typography>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                validationSchema={schema}
              >
                {props => {
                  const {
                    values: { email, password },
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleChange,
                    isValid,
                    setFieldTouched
                  } = props;
                  const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                    e.persist();                
                    handleChange(e);
                    setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                    setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value }));  
                  };
                  return (
                    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation);FormSubmitted();RedirectionToPanel()}}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        fullWidth
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"     
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                      /> 
                      {submitted && ShowError()}

                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <Button className='button-center'
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                        // onClick={handleOpen}
                        style={{
                          background: '#6c74cc',
                          borderRadius: 3,
                          border: 0,
                          color: 'white',
                          height: 48,
                          padding: '0 30px'
                        }}
                      >                       
                        Submit</Button>
                    </form>
                  )
                }}
              </Formik>
            </div>
          </Container>
          )
        }
      </Mutation>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

When I hit the submit button, I check the console for what happens inside the **RedirectionToPanel()** function. The first time, 'Ha' is printed but when I click on it for the second time, **both 'Ha' & 'Finally' are printed**. However, the redirection still doesn't happen.

If I use `{submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}`after Mutation, I get this error on mutation:

```
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type '(mutateFunction: MutationFunction<any, Record<string, any>>, result: MutationResult<any>) => Element | null', but multiple children were provided.ts(2746)
```

If I use it after the return and before mutation, I get syntax errors on && and }.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `submitForm` and `FormSubmitted` both contain asynchronous operations. This means that calling them one after another followed by `RedirectionToPanel` does not guarantee that they execute in that order. Consider using the `useEffect` hook to do the redirect once the token is set.

Also, the reason why the page is not redirecting is because you are not returning the Redirect component into the DOM tree. You can fix this by inserting it with a conditional statement that checks the submitted state

```
//when localStorage.getItem('token') changes, execute the callback
useEffect(() => {
    setSubmitted(true);
}, [localStorage.getItem('token')])

...

return (
...
    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation);}}>
...
    //This line can be anywhere in the return. Even at the end is fine
        {submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}
    <Container />
);
```

If you want to do this without useEffect, you can use `setSubmitted` within `submitForm`. But even then, you must have `{submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}` somewhere in your DOM

```
  function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    const { email, password } = state;
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
      setSubmitted(true);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    }
  }

return (
...
    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation);}}>
...
    //This line can be anywhere in the return. Even at the end is fine
        {submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}
    <Container />
);
```

Comment: but I am already using ```{submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}```in my RedirectToPanel function to check the submitted state. Shouldn't it work? How/where else would I use it in the DOM?

Comment: Is there no way to do it without useEffect?

Comment: I think you are confusing it with `submitted && localStorage.getItem('token')`. `submitted && localStorage.getItem('token')` is a condition while `{submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}` inserts `<Redirect to='/panel'/>` when `submitted` is a truthy value. i.e. not false. I shall edit my answer to show an appropriate place for the redirect

Comment: Ah I see. But still, if I use this as it is after the return, I get an error on && that ```',' expected.```and ```')' expected.ts(1005)```on the closing } bracket

Comment: @a125 You are supposed to use it within the return, not after. Perhaps you could show what you have changed in the original post?

Comment: By "after" I meant in the beginning on the return. In between the return & mutation lines. See the edited code. This is what I have changed so far.

Comment: @a125 Ah ok my bad. I was not aware of what the Mutation component actually does. It seems like it was a bad place to put it. You can put it at the very end right before `<Container/>` instead.

Comment: Yes it works now, even without having to use useEffect(). Do you think it can cause problems in the future?

Comment: @a125 It should be alright. localStorage is a synchronous API so the sequence of execution should be preserved unless you change or add anything big.

Comment: Could you please also have a look at this? I encountered another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580140/stop-redirection-onsubmit-display-error-message-instead

Answer (score 0):

As @wxker stated, you need to return `<Redirect>` elements in the render method in order for the redirect to actually occur. E.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-rgb-d0g8e.

Comment: The problem in my case is that the setState happens late and redirection function runs earlier. Also, if I use ```{submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}``` in the beginning of my return(), I get syntax errors as described in the comments on the above answer