# How to automatic redirect home page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to automatic redirect home page after click on update button, here is my `handleSubmit` code:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // access data from backend
    axios
      .put(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/post/${slug}`, {
        title,
        content,
        user,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const { title, content, slug, user } = response.data;

        setState({ ...state, title, content, slug, user });
        alert(`Post Title ${response.data.title} is Updated`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  };
```

Here I have use a alert when my post has been updated then show me, but now I need to redirect my home page. when I click on `update` button

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Why use react and then reload? What is the point then? Or do you want to redirect TO the home page?

Comment: You're using React, so are you also using react-router? Or how did you set up your navigation?

Comment: If this is a React app, and you are using *react-router-dom* (or any other routing library), you can redirect using the routing library. For example: `Redirect` form *react-router-dom* or you can also do `history.push('/__path__')`.

Comment: Ok, then should I do like this `import {Router} = require('react-router');
Router.push('/');`

Comment: Do `history.push('/path_here')`

Comment: Docs link: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: Also: the correct duplicate is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useHistory hook.

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Component = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // access data from backend
    axios
      .put(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/post/${slug}`, {
        title,
        content,
        user,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const { title, content, slug, user } = response.data;

        setState({ ...state, title, content, slug, user });
        alert(`Post Title ${response.data.title} is Updated`);
        // ********redirection here **********
        history.push("/");
        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  };
  
}
```