# How to redirect from old URL to new URL in React JS? Related SEO Changes?

Tags: reactjs, url, redirect, seo

- Old Url: `http://localhost:3000/aboutus`
- New Url: `http://localhost:3000/about-us`

I want to redirect the user from old URL to new URL. If he/she goes to old URL redirect to new URL.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to redirect a page using React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.