# Is there anyway to prevent login form from rendering when an authenticated user tries to access "/login" route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

In my react app in my `<Login \>` component I check if user has a valid JWT with useEffect hook and then redirect them to `"/"` .

But every time I try to access the `"/login"` route I see a flicker for a second (showing my login form) and then i get redirected to the homepage.

Is there anyway to get away from this flicker?

I tried conditional routing in my routes in `App.js` file to check user JWT and if it's valid, redirect to homepage and if not render `<Login />` component.

```
<Route path="/login" element={ isValid ? <Navigate to={"/"} replace /> : <Login /> }
```

But the problem still remains and there is a flicker.

Is there a way to avoid this flicker? or it's just normal.

**[FIXED]**

I was using promises inside my useEffect to validate the token and then using the useState hook to set the authentication state of users.

Then I noticed that if I put a loading component until the validation gets done, the useEffect hook (validation) will never run and will never check the JWT and run the `setAuthState(true)` because *it's stuck on a loading component.*

```
if (authState === undefined) return <Loading />
```

***So, I replaced the code in promises with an async function to await the value and set the authentication state and get this done.***

Comment: I think it would be better to show a loader component until you have the value of JWT token. Once you have the value, based on that show the login form or navigate him to the next page.

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel Yeah I was planning to do this but because I was using promises inside my useEffect the value of JWT would never change actually because the code would stuck on a loading component, I fixed the problem by using an async function instead of promises to await the value before showing loading component.

Answer (score 0):

Use the useLayoutEffect hook instead. This will fire just before the screen repaints.

`useLayoutEffect(() => ...`

https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect

Answer (score 0):

When on CSR, It cannot be done, the component needs to be rendered first, then it will decide whether to redirect the client or not,
to do so, use a server side validation for your session and redirect the user from the server, not from user's client.