# How to redirect to login page on click of logout in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http

Sorry for my bad English, English is not my first language.

Hi, I am new to react JS, in the below code everything is working fine but when I click logout handler it shows

> "
>    ×
>      TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>   "

Can you please let me know how can i redirect to login page on click of logout handler,

I tried all possibilities like:

this.props.history.push('somepath')
this.context.history.push('somepath')
but nothing worked for me I researched lot but didn't found actual answer.

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter,Link,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Contact from './contact';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    logoutHandler =(e) => {
        this.props.history.replace('/login')
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <header>
                        <Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
                    </header>
                    <div>
                        <Route path='/contact' Component={Contact}></Route>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" onClick={e=>this.logoutHandler(e)}>Logout</a>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;`
```

Comment: Since, you are using an 'a' tag. First change the href="#" to href="javascript:void(0)". And in the logoutHandler instead of "replace" use "push"

Comment: Possible duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086387/how-to-redirect-to-home-pagein-jsx-after-logout-in-react/77287123#77287123

Answer (score 2):

Use `WithRouter` to access history object

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react';
 import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import {BrowserRouter,Link,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Contact from './contact';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    logoutHandler =(e) => {
        this.props.history.push('/login')
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <header>
                        <Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
                    </header>
                    <div>
                        <Route path='/contact' Component={Contact}></Route>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" onClick={e=>this.logoutHandler(e)}>Logout</a>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `this.props.history.push('/login')`.

The reason for your error is that you are not wrapping your component export with HOC react router.

Add the import 
`import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';` and wrap your component export like so `export default withRouter(Home);`. This way the history prop will be injected into your Home component.