# How to correctly redirect after the user clicked logout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

the app function have a router and i well use them in the components thanks for help ....

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='App'>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <Login />
          </Route>

          <Route path='/SignUp'>
            <SignUp />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Route
          path='/Student/:id'
          exact
          render={({ match }) => <Student match={match} />}
        />
        <Route
          path='/Admin/:id'
          exact
          render={({ match }) => <Admin match={match} />}
        />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

just need to use redirect after the admin decided to click on the logout button
without using usehistory.

```
const Admin = () => {
  const logoutfunc = async () => {
    let connectToServer = new ConnectToServer();
    //let session=await connectToServer.getSession()
    connectToServer.logout();
  };

  const redirect = () => {
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/' }} />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          logoutfunc();
          redirect();
        }}
      >
        logout
      </button>
      <Cards />
      <TableStudent />
      <Cohorts />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089386/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-a-page-using-react-router

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086387/how-to-redirect-to-home-pagein-jsx-after-logout-in-react/77287123#77287123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have to do is this:

```
const Admin = () => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const logoutfunc = async () => {
    let connectToServer = new ConnectToServer();
    //let session=await connectToServer.getSession()
    connectToServer.logout();
    setRedirect(true);
  };

  if(redirect){
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/' }} />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={logoutfunc}
      >
        logout
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

or use `push` method like this:

```
const Admin = () => {
  const logoutfunc = async () => {
    let connectToServer = new ConnectToServer();
    //let session=await connectToServer.getSession()
    connectToServer.logout();
    history.push({ pathname: '/' })
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={logoutfunc}
      >
        logout
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: if i use the useState i can change it with the client  inspect thats wrong idea true??

Comment: @RianHalabi what do you mean you can change it with client inspect? and if you can change it, why should it be wrong? anything that you put in react can be change from the client if the user knows how, react is a client side application, don't forget that