# Redirect to login page after logout

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-navigation

I'm kind of new to React stuff, I've been playing with it for like a week, and I'm stuck at pretty simple thing I think.

After user clicks "logout" I want the function logOut to also redirect him to other page (atm login page, cause its the only other page I've got). However, using navigate, I am having this error about Hooks.

> Line 13:21:  React Hook "useNavigate" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

I've tried to workaround this however I don't think I fully understand whats the matter here. If anyone could simply point to me, what should I re-write to get my code going, I would be grateful.

My App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import RegistrationForm from './registry/Register';
import LoginForm from './registry/Login';
import WelcomeBack from './pages/Main';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component { 
}

render() {


const nav = useNavigate();

    function logOut() {         
        localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
        nav("/login");
    }

    function isLoggedIn() {
        const tokenValue = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

        if (tokenValue != null) {
            return true;
        }
        //here navigate to '/login'
        return false;
    }

    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                    <a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>

                    <a href="/register" class="split">Register</a>
                    <a href="/login" class="split">Login</a>



                      <div className="logout" >
                            <a href="#" class="split" onClick={logOut}>Logout</a>
                        </div>

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onClick={myFunction}>
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <Routes>
                        <Route path='/register' element={<RegistrationForm />}/>
                        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginForm />} />
                        <Route path='/' element={<WelcomeBack />} />
                    </Routes>
                </div>
            </Router>

        );
    }
}
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    }

    else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can't use hooks in class components. You can get the `navigation` object through props. Try something like this `this.props.navigation.navigate('YouScreen', {paramsIfAny})`

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118450/5519872

Comment: Try this also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086387/how-to-redirect-to-home-pagein-jsx-after-logout-in-react/77287123#77287123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks are not working in the class component, if u want to use you can wrap it in a HOC.

```
function withNavigation(Component) {
  return props => <Component {...props} navigate={useNavigate()} />;
}
```

and then

```
class BlogPost extends React.Component {

  redirect(){
    this.props.navigate('/url')
  }
  render() {
    
    // ...
  }
}

export default withNavigation(BlogPost);
```

check this issue for more information [Github Issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8146)

Answer (score 0):

- first thing you can't use react hooks ( useNavigate ) inside class component, instead you can use withRouter in class component.
  https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter
- second thing, you forgot to put the code between the curly braces

you should do it like this:

```html
 class App extends Component { 
...
// put your code here between the curly braces

   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calling function to redirection on Logout button clicked

logoutCall = () => {
    window.localStorage.clear();
};  
goLogin = () => {
   // this.props.navigation.navigate("/login");
   <Link to="/login"></Link>
  };    

<Link className="linkLogoutClass" to="/login" onClick={this.logoutCall}><img style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} className="logoutImageStyle " src={logout} onClick={this.goLogin}   ></img> Logout</Link>
```